# Cancel the timer task at a certain time

Tags: java, timer

I have code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = c.getTime();
        if (c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) > 22 && date.getMinutes() >= 55) {
            this.cancel();
        }
        // .....
    }
}, 0, 60000);
```

I want this taks to be killed at `11:55 P.M.`
Any idea why it's not being killed?

Comment: Try debugging and see what happens.

Comment: I got the answer.. the timer was not picking time correctly... I was expecting my system time to be picked but the server on which the code was running was in different time zone. This was the issue because of whcih condition was not being satisfied.